# Yii2 installing extension from private git server - framework not see it

Tags: git, composer-php, yii-extensions, yii2

I've created my yii2 extension. I keep it on my private git server. I managed the extension to be downloaded through composer using following code:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "author/yii2-user",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "source": {
                "url": "ssh://git@my.server.pl/srv/git/user.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "origin/master"
            }
        }
    }
],
```

and `"author/yii2-user": "*",` in `require` section. 
It all works fine but there is one problem. After downloading extension, composer should add it to the `yiisoft\extension.php` file but it's not being added.

In my extension I have composer.json file like this:

```
{
"name": "author/yii2-user",
"description": "Auth and user manager for our apps",
"keywords": ["yii", "admin", "auth"],
"type": "yii2-extension",
"support": {
    "issues": "",
    "source": ""
},
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "j2",
        "email": "j2@j2.j2"
    }
],
"require": {
    "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "author\\user\\": ""
    }
}
```

}

I'm trying to find a solution but it's a hard one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use the `"type": "package"` repository if you have the source code under your own control. Every info you have to add there can be figured out by Composer itself if you use the `"type": "vcs"` repository and give the URL of the source code server.

The correct way would be:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "ssh://git@my.server.pl/srv/git/user.git"
    }
],
```

The Composer scans this repository for a `composer.json`, parses it and then knows all the metadata like name, type (probably important if you want to install it as a yii extension), version or branch etc.

The package type does only exist to allow anybody who needs one particular software which is not maintained anymore and therefore a missing `composer.json` will never be added and/or registration at packagist.org will never be happening to substitute this lack of information. Don't use it for your own software, ever.

Comment: I changed vcs to git to make it more accurate. Thanx!