# Composer autoloading psr-4 not adding namespace to autoload_psr4.php

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I am using in a project a custom repository in github that contains my set of instruments.

The project correctly imports the package inside the /vendor directory,but i cannot use any of the class, because it is not autoloading the contents of the package.

My package composer.json file looks as follows:

```
{
"name": "mynamespace/toolbox",
"description": "Asdfoobar.",
"keywords": ["mynamespace", "toolbox"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4"          
},
"require-dev": {
    "codeception/codeception": "2.0.2",
    "codeception/specify": "0.3.6",
    "codeception/verify": "0.2.7",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Mynamespace\\": "src/Mynamespace",
        "Mocks\\": "tests/Mocks"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [

    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php vendor/bin/codecept run"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
```

}

Inside the project instead, the composer.json file looks as follows:

```
    "require": {
       [...stuff...]
       "Mygitrepo/toolbox": "dev-master" 
    },
    "repositories": [        
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "Mygitrepo/toolbox",
            "version": "master",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/Mygitrepo/toolbox.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

The final autoload_psr4.php after doing composer update, composer dump looks like following:
No trace of "Mynamespace"

```
return array(
  'Monolog\\' => array($vendorDir . '/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog'),
  'Ivory\\LuceneSearchBundle\\' => array($vendorDir . '/egeloen/lucene-search-bundle'),
  'Facebook\\' => array($vendorDir . '/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook'),
);
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509654/yii2-installing-extension-from-private-git-server-framework-not-see-it/24518151#24518151) applies here as well.

Because you are providing a "type:package" entry in "repositories", you are disabling the `composer.json` file in the package.

And there is no autoloading defined in the package definition, so the package is not autoloaded at all.

Solution: Don't use the "type:package" entry for repositories you own and which have a `composer.json` file inside.